# How to enable invisible ReCAPTCHA on checkbox onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, invisible-recaptcha

I am struggling with an recaptcha issue on my local. I am trying to build a register form. All examples about recaptcha are about buttons. What I want is to pop-up recaptcha modal to user when he/she clicks on checkbox which says ' I have read and accept terms and conditions.' When he/she solves recaptcha then checkbox would be checked. Here what I am trying

It did not work, after that I tried this onClick method did not work because it writes Script Error on console.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
     <script>
       function controlFunction() {
         grecaptcha.render()
       }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='checkbox-form' action="?" method="POST">
     <input onclick="controlFunction()" type="checkbox" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_LOCAL_KEY" data-callback='onClick' id="termsConditions" class="termsOkay">
     <label for="termsConditions" generated="true">I have read and accepted <a target="_blank" href="/sales-terms-and-conditions/">Terms and Conditions</a> </label>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know code is a mess because I tried so many different thing and this is what I got. I am really confused. All I want is if user checks the checkbox let captcha popup. When solved, checkbox is checked. How can I do it? I tried to use handleChange but could not make it either.

Here is my whole code:

```
<?php
// Google reCaptcha secret key
$secretKey  = "REMOVEDCONTENTBYME";

$statusMsg = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['captcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['captcha-response'])){
        // Get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretKey.'&response='.$_POST['captcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success){
            //Contact form submission code goes here ...
  
            $statusMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
        }else{
            $statusMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    }
}
?>

<?php  $businessTypes = [
    'Full Service',
    'Quick Service',
    'Bars and Clubs',
]; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/fom8rbw.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/thegem/css/main.css">
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback" async defer></script>
    <script>
    var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.execute();
    };

    function setResponse(response) { 
    document.getElementById('captcha-response').value = response; 
    }
    </script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <style>
        html, body, .site-content {
            padding: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
            background-color:#fff;
        }
        .textwidget a {
            font-family: 'proxima-nova',sans-serif !important;
        }
        .d-none {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .section{
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        .demo-form input, .demo-form select, .demo-form textarea {
            border: 1px solid #e31d93;
        }
        .demo-form input {
            text-indent: 12px;
        }
        .form-control {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(1.5em + 1.3rem + 2px);
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #495057;
            background-color: #fff;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            border: 1px solid #ced4da;
            border-radius: .40rem;
        }
        .row-m-t{
             margin-top : 0px
        }
        
    </style>
    
<div id="page" class="site">
    
    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area demo-form">
            <main id="main" class="site-main">
        <div class="section blog-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center"><h1 style="padding-bottom: 10rem;">Request FOrm</h1></div>
                <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form class="demo-form" method="post" onsubmit="return false" style=" position: relative; bottom: 35px; ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 border-danger form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control validate" data-validate="validateText" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" style=" background-color: #fff;">
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control validate" data-validate="validateText" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name"style=" background-color: #fff;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row row-m-t">
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control validate" data-validate="validateText" name="companyName" placeholder="Group name"style=" background-color: #fff;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control validate" data-validate="validatePhone" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone number"style=" background-color: #fff;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row row-m-t">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control validate" data-validate="validateEmail" name="emailAddress" placeholder="email"style=" background-color: #fff;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="row row-m-t">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <select name="businessType" id="businessType" class="form-control validate" data-validate="validateText">
                                        <option value=""><?php _e('Select Your Business Type...', 'myfirm'); ?></option>
                                        <?php foreach ($businessTypes as $type): ?>
                                            <option><?php _e($type, 'myfirm'); ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach ;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row radio">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p style="font-size:13px;"><?php _e('Validate by', 'myfirm'); ?>:</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row radio" style="font-size:13px;">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline col-md-6">
                                        <input type="radio" id="validateByPhone" checked value="phoneNumber" name="validateBy" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <label style="font-size:12px;    transform: scale(1.2);
    position: relative;
    left: 1rem;" class="custom-control-label" for="validateByPhone"><?php _e('Phone Number', 'myfirm'); ?></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline col-md-6">
                                        <input type="radio" id="validateByEmailAddess" value="emailAddress" name="validateBy" class="custom-control-input">
                                        <label style="font-size:12px;    transform: scale(1.2);
    position: relative;
    left: 1rem; top:5px;" class="custom-control-label" for="validateByEmailAddess"><?php _e('Email Address', 'myfirm'); ?></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row radio">
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="position: relative;right: 13px;">
                                <div class="custom-radio custom-control-inline col-md-12">
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="REMOVEDCONTENTBYME" data-badge="inline" data-size="invisible" data-callback="setResponse"></div>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="captcha-response" name="captcha-response" />
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="captcha-response" class="termsOkay" style=" background-color: #fff;">
                                    <label for="captcha-response" class="error" generated="true" style="position: relative;bottom: 5px;">&nbsp;I have read and accepted <a target="_blank" href="/sales-terms-and-conditions/">Terms and Conditions</a> </label>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="verification-code d-none">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="verification-code"><?php _e('A verification code has been sent to your phone number!', 'myfirm') ?></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" placeholder="<?php _e('Verification code', 'myfirm');?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row row-m-t">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <button class="btn btn-myfirm send-verification-code" disabled="disabled" style="width: 100% !important;height: 125% !important;font-size: 15px;"><?php _e('Request a Demo', 'myfirm'); ?></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </main>
</div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
  function admSelectCheck(obj)
  {
    var nameSelect = obj.value;
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
      admOptionValue = 'United States of America|+1';
      if(admOptionValue == nameSelect){
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('input.termsOkay').change(function() {
    if (!jQuery('input.termsOkay').is(':checked')) {
        jQuery('.send-verification-code').prop('disabled', true)
    } else{
        jQuery('.send-verification-code').prop('disabled', false)
    }
        
})
})
</script>


</html>
```

The part I am trying to make it work

```
                    <div class="row radio">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="position: relative;right: 13px;">
                        <div class="custom-radio custom-control-inline col-md-12">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="REMOVEDCONTENTBYME" data-badge="inline" data-size="invisible" data-callback="setResponse"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="captcha-response" name="captcha-response" />
                            <input type="checkbox" id="captcha-response" class="termsOkay" style=" background-color: #fff;">
                            <label for="captcha-response" class="error" generated="true" style="position: relative;bottom: 5px;">&nbsp;I have read and accepted <a target="_blank" href="/sales-terms-and-conditions/">Terms and Conditions</a> </label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It looks like you forgot to put your php code. From my memories from years ago -- you had to call a hpp function that calls Google's API and then you had to save the response into your $_SESSION. Do you have something similar in your php code?  :)

Comment: @tftd No actually I don't have a session in my code because I did not see it in google documents. How can I write it? I guess you are telling me to start a session and do something with it? Working on for many hours and really need help :)